# Double integration with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I know how to do double integration but I'm stuck on this problem involving polar coordinates.

$$\int\int_{R}y^2dA,$$
where $R$ is the disc $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

I'm not sure how to work out the limits, etc for this problem. Any help?

Comment: So what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \implies 0\leq r \leq 1$.

$\theta$ sweeps a full revolution $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$,

And recall that $y = r \sin \theta$, so $y^2 = r^2\sin^2\theta$.

That gives us $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (r^2\sin^2 \theta)\,r \,dr\,d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (r^3\sin^2 \theta)\,dr\,d\theta$$

Can you take it from here?